# Change json keys in JMSSerializerBundle

Tags: php, json, symfony, jmsserializerbundle

Suppose I have an entity with a single field: 'userName' whos corresponding column name in the table is 'user_name'. When I serialize object of that entity, it returns a json with column name of the userName field like this:

```
{"user_name": "davit"}
```

but what I want is for jms serializer to use entity field name (userName) as the json key:

```
{"userName": "davit"}
```

Is this doable?

I read a lot of articles beginning with the documentation, but failed to find a reference to this...

Thanks a lot for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you use annotations but you can use @serializedName

http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#serializedname

Comment: How could have I missed that :) Thank you so much melvin

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which configuration format you're using (XML, YAML or Annotations) but they all have a `serialized_name` setting that allows you to configure the serialized name of a property.

It's [`@serializedName`](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#serializedname) if you use annotations, `serialized_name` if you use [YAML](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/yml_reference) and `serialized-name` if you use [XML](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/xml_reference).

[The documentation](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer#documentation) contains reference (example) configurations in all formats.